# Public variable to save the sheet last clicked on

Tags: excel, vba, public

I have a workbook that has several sheets that contain cells that open up the same userform to be filled out.

Currently, closing the form returns the workbook to one page in particular.

I am trying to return to the page that was previously being worked on.

I set up a public worksheet variable (`wsWorking`) that would be set to the sheet last clicked on before opening the `UserForm`.

I get:

> Run Time Error '9': Subscript out of range

and the debug message shows my `wsWorking` variable as empty.

If I put in the name of a sheet instead of trying to use the variable, I can open it to the page I want.

Declaration: '(in my ThisWorkbook module, (General) (Descriptions)

```
Public wsWorking As Worksheet
```

Attempted Set: '(In a private module, extraneous code removed)

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Set wsWorking = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MRL 1")
    Dim clickRow As Integer
    Dim ClickCol As Integer
```

Attempted Use: (in a different, private module)

```
Private Sub CloseForm_Click()
    Call SaveFormToScorecard_Click
    Unload Me
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsWorking).Activate
End Sub
```

I tried setting the wsWorking in the general declarations for the module, when the worksheet is activated, and created a public sub in the module solely for the purpose of setting that variable, and none of it works.

Changing

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsWorking).Activate
```

to

```
wsWorking.Activate
```

gives me a new error

> Run-Time Error '424': Object Required

I don't believe the setting of the variable in the one module is transferring to the other one.

Comment: it should be just: `wsWorking.Activate`  The variable is already a worksheet object that includes the workbook.  Or if you want you can do: `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsWorking.name).Activate` but that is the long way around.

Comment: Public variables should be declared in standard modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ThisWorkbook` is a class module with a `PredeclaredId` attribute that makes it accessible from anywhere, but its members are still *its* members. You can access any public member of `ThisWorkbook` from anywhere in your code, by qualifying it with the predeclared `ThisWorkbook` object:

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.wsWorking.Name
```

If you want a *global* variable, then you cannot use an object module, because objects require an instance (the `ThisWorkbook` instance being automagically created doesn't make it any less of an object instance). Declare a public variable in a *standard module* instead, and then you can access it unqualiifed from anywhere in your code, whether to read it or to write it.

Wait. Say this out loud.

> and then you can access it unqualiifed from anywhere in your code, whether to read it or to write it.

This probably isn't a good idea. Consider declaring it `Private`, and only exposing it as a `Public Property Get` so that it *cannot* be overwritten at any time by anything anywhere.

This should work if it's `Public` in `ThisWorkbook`:

```
Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Set ThisWorkbook.wsWorking = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MRL 1")
    Dim clickRow As Integer '<~ this will explode at row 32,768. Use a Long!
    Dim ClickCol As Integer '<~ should still be a Long
```

A few severe issues here:

> ````
>     Call SaveFormToScorecard_Click '<~ event handlers aren't supposed to be invoked like this
>     Unload Me '<~ self-destructing object, danger!
>     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsWorking).Activate '<~ will throw error 1004 End Sub ```
> ````

`ActiveWorkbook` is *whatever workbook happens to be active at the time*, and while that's *probably* `ThisWorkbook`, there's a good chance it's not. And whenever it isn't, this *will* blow up. `wsWorking` is a `Worksheet` reference, it's redundant to dereference it (by name, implicitly!) from a `Sheets` collection - just `ThisWorkbook.wsWorking.Activate` would do.

Note that if `wsWorking` exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, you're probably better off just using its own predeclared instance.

Every `Worksheet` module has a `(Name)` property that is the name of the VB project component; this value becomes the name of a global object, just like `ThisWorkbook`. See [implicit containing workbook reference](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitContainingWorkbookReference) Rubberduck inspection for more info.